# Ipython 0.13.1: Ipython.display.Image doesn't load local png files in notebook

Tags: png, ipython

I can't figure out why I can't load a local png file into my ipython notebook. I have in a cell:

from IPython.display import Image
i = Image('../heavy_vortex_3/frames/x_snap_n0000000.png')
i

and instead of seeing the image, i get a little "broken picture" image. Remote pngs work fine, for example:

Image(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bf/Firefox.png')

happily renders that little fox guy. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image assume by default you are passing an url and will display an img tag with the href attribute set to the value you passed. You are basically trying to access

`http://localhost:8888/../heavy_vortex_3/frames/x_snap_n0000000.png`

And probably unless you use some kind of middleware, your asking that to the ipython webserver that have no clue of what you wish.

I think what you want is to display an image with respect to the current working directory of the kernel. So you want to use the `filename` ( If I remember correctly) kwarg.:

`Image(filename='../heavy_vortex_3/frames/x_snap_n0000000.png')`

Which will actually read the file, and send it on the wire.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just realized I misread the docs. Thank you!